# Using span to insert tab in textview

Tags: android, textview, tabstop

Is there a way to add a tab character to a piece of text using `span` in `textview`? From the developer documentation, I came across `TabStopSpan` ([see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TabStopSpan.html)) and tried to use it in a `TextView` like so:

```
String source = "Hello World! Let's select some text!!";

        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(source);
        s.setSpan(new TabStopSpan() {
            @Override
            public int getTabStop() {
                return 100;
            }
        }, 5, 10, 0);
ed.setText(s, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Where ed is a `TextView`. The above snippet does not do anything and the documentation is so less as to be pretty much useless. Is there any way to add a tab character to a `TextView` using spans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add "\t" for a tab, "\n" for a new line.
For example:

```
String source = "Hello!\tLets select some text!";
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. combination of "\t" and TabStopSpannable will do the trick.
The snippet below adds a tab between firstString and secondString:

```
    SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder(firstString +"\t"+ secondString);
    span.setSpan(new TabStopSpan.Standard(600), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
    }

    ((TextView) v).setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Be careful to use a meaningful value in the TabStopSpan.Standard constructor, preferably based on  screendimensions.

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
public static SpannableStringBuilder getTabText(String text, float stop)
{
    int column = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, stop, SystemMaster.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    span.setSpan(new TabStopSpan.Standard(column), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return span;
}
```

and then

```
Text text = "xx \t yy \n aa \t bb";
SpannableStringBuilder sp = TextHelper.getTabText(text, 100);
tv.setText(sp);
```