# How to display tabs(whitespace) coming from MySQL database correctly on both in Android and IOS app?

Tags: android, mysql, ios

I have following data in my db row:

```
Espresso:                           7,00

Double Espresso:                    8,00

Ristretto:                          7,00

Espresso Machiato:                  8,00

Espresso Con Panna:                 8,00
```

I write it on Word, then copy & paste to MySQL editor. When I save it, my IOS and Android apps cannot show the prices aligned because of the tab characters.

[image]

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

The best way-  those 2 things are different data and are in different columns in your database, I would expect (if not, you need to fix your schema).  So put the 2 strings in separate TextViews, and align the text view in xml.

Comment: It's not possible for now due to my schema.

Comment: if you can't split them due to your schema you can always parse the text, and use separated TextViews as @Gabe Sechan recommends or maybe use a [TabStop] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TabStopSpan.html) span see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121125/using-span-to-insert-tab-in-textview

Answer (score 3):

First you can split the data from tab character and use formatting like below in java. I believe in objective-c it should be similar.

```
    String ehe = String.format("%-20s : \t %4dTL \n","ehemehe",23);
    String ehe2 = String.format("%-20s : \t %4dTL \n","ehemeheadawd",44);
    System.out.println(ehe);
    System.out.println(ehe2);
```

Output it produces is

```
ehemehe              :     23TL 

ehemeheadawd         :     44TL
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the "/t" chars with "" before you display the text. by using

```
String.replace("/t","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed-width font if you have precalculated the number of spaces.